# remove all dashes from a string

Tags: php, string, preg-replace, character, str-replace

I've created this code to remove all dashes from a string, then convert all spaces to underscores.

```
preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', str_replace('-', '', $header_tags_array['title']))
```

It does work, but I am fairly new to this and am curious if their is a better way to write this or a faster way to execute the same request.

Any ideas?

Rob

Comment: are you trying to make a slug?

Comment: http://cubiq.org/the-perfect-php-clean-url-generator

Comment: Thanks @cmorrissey! That looks like a good read. Love the "iconv" .

Comment: Thanks @Pedro, for the title and post rewrite. English makes more sense then PHP for a title, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace can work with arrays, you could do:

```
$str  = 'a  -bc-d-e  f';
$str = preg_replace(array('/\s+/','/-/'), array('_', ''), $str);
echo $str,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
a_bcde_f
```

Comment: interesting approach. Thanks, for the idea, @Toto. Any idea which runs faster?